# Numbers in call signs

Tags: contemporary-latin, military

Various military vehicles have often call signs containing a numbers.
For a quick example, you can watch a little bit of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WBG2rJZGW8&t=1m45s).
I would like to know how to render such call signs in Latin, especially regarding the numerals.

To make the question concrete, how should I translate "red 5" to Latin?
Should I use an ordinal (*rubrum quintum*), a cardinal (*rubrum quinque*), or something else?
The neuter can be replaced with another gender if one reads it as "the fifth red ship" or something similar.
In any case, the final Latin call sign should be concise, and implied words like "ship" have to be left out.

I think the questions "How to translate call signs from English (or some other language) to Latin?" and "How to write call signs in Latin?" are identical.
Whatever the Latin convention is (choice of gender and ordinal or cardinal), it should be followed in both cases.
Perhaps comparison to other languages would help, but I couldn't find information on reading out numbers in call signs.
I only know that both English and Finnish use cardinals.

I feel that ordinals are the way to go here, but I don't know any precedent for call signs in Latin.

Comment: What do other languages do? Are you asking about how to translate English call signs, or how a Latin-speaking person would label a military vehicle? For simple translation, I cannot see why the cardinal isn't preferred. It's not like "red 5" means anything grammatically in English anyway.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I would prefer ordinal, since *red 5* presumably comes after *red 4* and before *red 6,* and that's practically the definition of ordinal.

Comment: @Anonym I do not understand. Are you saying that the cardinal number 5 doesn't come after 4 and before 6?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I added a new paragraph (third). I don't know what other languages do, and it seems to be hard to search. I have no feeling as to whether one should prefer cardinals or ordinals in call signs or any kind of codes in Latin. Any kind of insight would be a useful answer.

Comment: @Anonym By that reasoning I would expect that "red 5" is read as "red fifth" in English, but it isn't. Nevertheless, Latin does have a slight tendency to prefer ordinals where English would use cardinals and I might use an ordinal too.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta English often uses cardinals as ordinals - i.e., *chapter one* is just an idiomatic way to say *the first chapter* - but Latin doesn't.

Comment: Just a note on this. In English, callsigns typically have reserved meaning. The numbers aren't intended as ordinals but rather signifiers. In Afghanistan I was "Demon 4 Bravo Delta". Demon was our unit ID, 4 was our squad ID, B was our team ID, and D because I drove our HMMWV. In the US, 6 typically identifies a leader - Demon 6 was our platoon leader. The number can be replaced with the word "Actual" which is typically a commander, thus Demon Actual was our commanding officer. If calling a military vehicle, you typically call the unit ID. Naval ships and aircraft can differ slightly.